# How to combine ngIf with ngFor

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular.

I would like to to print list of products, which are in relation with distributor. For that I thought about combaining *ngFor *ngIf so here is a code:

```
<div class="distributors-here ui-g-12" *ngIf="distributors">
  <h2 >Distributors  <i class="fa icon fa-plus"(click)="showDialog()"></i></h2>
  <p class="error-message" *ngIf="errorMessage.length >0">Operation couldn't be executed:</p>
  <p class="error-message">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  <ul class="distributors-list ui-g-12">
    <li class="distributor-item ui-md-3 ui-g-6" *ngFor="let distributor of distributors ">
      <i class="fa icon fa-times remove-distributor"(click)="removeDistributor(distributor.id,distributor.name)"></i>
      <div class="distributor-item-content">
        <p>id: {{distributor.id}}</p>
        <p>name: {{distributor.name}}</p>
          <div *ngIf="products">
            <p>products</p>
            <ol>
              <li  *ngFor="let product of products" *ngIf="product.distributor.id == distributor.id">dist</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So I want to loop over the products array and if the distributor id of product matches with distributor id from other array I will have it printed new li element created.

Unfortunately I get an error:

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *
>
> [ERROR ->]*ngIf="product.distributor.id== distributor.id"

Does anyone knows how to refactor this code to make it work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Angular doesn't support more than one structural directive on the same element, so you should use the `ng-container` helper element here. FYI `ng-container` does not add an extra element to the DOM (the `ul` in Example 2 does get added to the DOM).

Example 1

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products" >
   <li *ngIf="product.distributor.id == distributor.id">{{ product?.name  }}</li>
</ng-container>
```

or

Example 2

```
<ul *ngFor="let product of products">
  <li *ngIf="product.distributor.id == distributor.id">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perhaps it's my idea, but the latest angular seems much less well-designed that Angular 1.* in a lot of areas. Perhaps this design serves an internal purpose, but it is definitely not helpful and it creates a huge mess. What if you wanted to use `*ngFor`, `*ngIf` and `*ngClass` at the same time? Also, if the above solution is what you always need to do, why doesn't angular do it itself internally by creating the ngContainer elements, instead of bugging you to do it? I recently switched to the latest angular from version 1.* and things look quite non-efficient in terms of saving you trouble.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use multiple structural directives on one html element.
For example you can instead place your `*ngFor` in a `<ng-container>` and wrap it around your `<li>` element. The advantage of `<ng-container>` is the fact, that it doesn't introduce extra levels of HTML.

```js
<ol>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
    <li *ngIf="product.distributor.id == distributor.id">dist</li>
  </ng-container>
</ol>
```

For more detail information have a look at the [Official Angular Documentation (One structural directive per host element)](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-host-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`<ng-container>`** to have ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="products">
   <p>products</p>
     <ol>
             <ng-container *ngFor="let product of products" >
             <li *ngIf="product.distributor.id == distributor.id">dist</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: can you actually use multiple ng-containers ?